# Form submit 400 required string parameter is not present

Tags: spring, forms, post, gwt

I'm trying to simple POST data from my form to my spring controller and I always getting the error message:

> the server responded with a status of 400 (Required String parameter
>   'profileId' is not present)

my Form within my uiBinder:

```
<g:FormPanel ui:field="formPanel">
        <g:HTMLPanel>

            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%"><g:HTML HTML="Profile ID:" /></td>
                    <td width="80%"><g:TextBox name="profileId" ui:field="profileId" width="300px" "/>

                    <td width="20%"><g:HTML HTML="Logo: " /></td>
                    <td width="80%"> <g:FileUpload name="logo" ui:field="logoUpload"/> </td>        
                </tr>           
            </table><br/>

        </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:FormPanel>
```

the submit within the view:

```
String actionUrl = com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "/create";
formPanel.setAction(actionUrl);
formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
formPanel.submit();
```

my spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public void create(@RequestParam("profileId") String profileId,
                   @RequestParam("logo") MultipartFile logo) throws BadRequestException, InternalException, NotFoundException{
    log.info("Request to create new user.");
}
```

The request payload tracked with chrome dev tool:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryX7km8vQwaC3LtjqO Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileId"
>
> test1
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryX7km8vQwaC3LtjqO Content-Disposition: form-data; name="logo"; filename="test1.png" Content-Type: image/png
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryX7km8vQwaC3LtjqO--

Eclipse console output:

```
[WARN] 400 - POST /create (127.0.0.1) 1495 bytes    Request headers
      Host: lokalhorst.com:55409
      Connection: keep-alive
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
      Referer: http://lokalhorst.com:55409/admin.html
      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
      Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
      Cookie: JSESSIONID=63vn7rbgnrqa
      Content-Length: 10244
      Pragma: no-cache
      Cache-Control: no-cache
      Origin: lokalhorst.com:55409
      Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryX7km8vQwaC3LtjqO    Response headers
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
      Content-Length: 1495
```

Thanks for any help.

[no duplication; also not helping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978333/http-status-400-required-string-parameter-xx-is-not-present)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MultipartForm handling with Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540249/multipartform-handling-with-spring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the `MulitpartResolver` into my servlet ( or applicationcontext )

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="250000"/>
</bean>
```

Already discussed in question [MultipartForm handling with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540249/multipartform-handling-with-spring)